# AJAX Call to PHP not returning any value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to use AJAX to call a function in a PHP file.

The function basically takes data that is submitted in the AJAX call, makes a couple other requests to API's, and gets a JSON object from an external API.

I want to send that JSON object back to my page, to be acted on by javascript.

Here is my code:

```
function secureGet(sumNam){

    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {sumNam: sumNam},
        url: 'get_score.php',
        success: function (json, state) {
            console.log(state);
            statsObject = json;
            console.log(statsObject);
        }
    })
}
```

**PHP:**

```
    <?php
require_once 'apikey.php';

if(isset($_POST['sumNam'])){
$name = $_POST['sumNam'];
secureProxy($name);
}

function secureProxy($summoner_name){

$url_one = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" . $summoner_name . "?api_key=" . $api_key;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_one);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result_one = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

$json_array = json_decode($result_one, true);

$summoner_id = $json_array[$summoner_name]['id'];

$url_two = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v2.2/matchhistory/" . $summoner_id .  "?rankedQueues=RANKED_SOLO_5x5,RANKED_TEAM_5x5&beginIndex=0&endIndex=10&api_key=" . $api_key;

    $ch2 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, $url_two);
    curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result_two = curl_exec($ch2);
    curl_close($ch2);

print_r($result_two);

}

?>
```

I think the call is successfully being made because in my console it says:

```
iGET XHR  http://127.0.0.1/b2p/get_score.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1551ms]
```

But the console isn't logging any information on the returned object.

Any reason as to why this might be happening?

Thanks!

```
<br />
<font size='1'><table class='xdebug-error xe-notice' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
<tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Notice: Undefined variable: api_key in C:\wamp\www\b2p\get_score.php on line <i>12</i>
```

...this goes on for a while

```
{"status": {"message": "Missing api key", "status_code": 401}}
```

But the API call works when I do it on its own.

Comment: You have ajax type as `GET` and you have sent data values in the data parameter.I dont think the $_GET in php will get any values this way?

Comment: Do I have to use $_POST?

Comment: If you use `GET` in the ajax call then i think data should be concatenated in `url` string

Comment: I just changed it to $_POST and still no luck.

Comment: Also changed to `POST` in the ajax call?

Comment: Yes, I will update with the new code

Comment: you specified `dataType: "json",` in your ajax call, but in php you are doing `print_r($result_two);` which does not return `json`. Per the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - `... The JSON data is parsed in a strict manner; any malformed JSON is rejected and a parse error is thrown.  ...`. You could try `echo json_encode($result_two);`, depending on the value of `$result_two`.

Comment: $result_two is a json object returned from the API that I call, but I will try this. One second.

Comment: You can also try logging the `error` callback of the ajax

Comment: Still nothing being returned. In my AJAX call, where I specify 'state', as the second argument, then I console.log(state);, shouldn't I see in the console either a success or failure?

Comment: no, you would only see `console.log(state);` on a `success` not `failure` as you only have `success: function (json, state) {... console.log(state); ...}`, but not `error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) { ... }` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Okay so I added an error handle, and it gives a code: 200, then the following message: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: try echo json_encode($result_two); instead of print_r($result_two);

Comment: So the `code:200` tells you that you that ajax successfully found the page, but the `SyntaxError: JSON.parse:` tells you that your returned data was invalid json. Since the error message is `unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` it means that the returned data does not start with `[` or `{`. If `$result_two` is valid json already, you can just echo it directly.

Comment: I echoed out the dataType: "json" line, and the ajax call worked. But it's returning some funky stuff. It's returning like web page bg colors and stuff like that, and then an error message at the end saying my API key is missing. I just tried the php page on its own to see if the call works and it indeed does so I have no idea what's going on

Comment: SEE THE UPDATED QUESTION FOR THE STUFF CONSOLE IS NOW ECHOING... it's echoing weird web page stuff

Comment: @CookieCoder what your are seeing are php notices, or warnings. If your have `error_reporting` enabled, they will echo the warnings out in any response that is sent right at the top. That will effectively invalidate any json you are sending back causing the 200 error, the error says your missing an API key somewhere, id start there, it will also give you the file name and line number

Comment: Go to **C:\wamp\www\b2p\get_score.php**  and check  **line 12**, whatever you are doing there requires an API key and you have not supplied one.

Comment: Very likely this line `$url_one = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" . $summoner_name . "?api_key=" . $api_key;`. Do you define ` $api_key` before this line executes?

Comment: Here is line 12: $url_one = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" . $summoner_name . "?api_key=" . $api_key;

Comment: > Do you define ` $api_key` before this line executes? Seems you probably do not.

Comment: Here is $api_key, defined: $api_key = "***";

Comment: Where is that defined? Keep in mind that PHP functions  (unlike javascript) create their own (variable scope)[http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php] and can only see variables that are either  passed into the function or are defined within the function itself

Comment: Got it! I wasnt passing the api key into the function. It was basically not in the scope of the function:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your are seeing are php notices, or warnings. If you have error_reporting enabled, they will echo the warnings out in any response that is sent right at the top. That will effectively invalidate any json you are sending back causing the 200 error, the error says your missing an API key somewhere, id start there, it will also give you the file name and line number.

Go to C:\wamp\www\b2p\get_score.php and check line 12, whatever you are doing there requires an API key and you have not supplied one.

It's very likely this line `$url_one = "https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/" . $summoner_name . "?api_key=" . $api_key;`.

Do you define `$api_key` before this line executes?

Keep in mind that PHP functions  (unlike javascript) create their own [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) and can only see variables that are either  passed into the function or are defined within the function itself.

**You need to pass your API key variable into the function when you call it.**

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not returning anything because in your PHP you haven't set the type you are returning.  Since you will be returning in Json format, you have to set your PHP header as below:

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    echo json_encode($result_two);

?>
```